Textblob-de missing deprecated module textblob.translate()
I want to run a sentiment analysis on German headlines and would like to use textblob-de for it. After installing as described here: https://textblob-de.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#installing-upgrading, I run into the error below when running a very simple script like so:
from textblob_de import TextBlobDE as TextBlob

text = "drama vor lampedusa : mehr als 1000 flüchtlinge im mittelmeer vor italien gerettet"

blob = TextBlob(text)

print(blob.sentiment)

The error states:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named
'textblob.translate'

The weird thing is that I have just now installed the package and textblob.translate is actually deprecated as stated in the change logs: https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/changelog.html
Regardless, textblobde seems to be using it. Do you see a way around this or is this model no longer feasible for German text?
